# Морфемный разбор слов широкий и кустарник

Tags: морфология, морфемика

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобрать слова по составу. В слове *широкий* корень *шир* или *широк*? В слове *кустарник* -- *куст* или *кустар*? И на какие источники можно сослаться, чтобы подтвердить правильность выделения корней?

Answer (score 2):

> В слове *широкий* корень *шир* или *широк*?.. И на какие источники
>   можно сослаться, чтобы подтвердить правильность выделения корней?

По Тихонову корень -- ***широк***. Слово ***широкий*** у него -- непроизводное. Слова ***широта, ширина, ширь*** у Тихонова образованы от слова ***широкий*** суффиксальным способом с усечением производящей основы.

Из его "Словаря-справочника по русскому языку" (М., 1997):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

===

> В слове *кустарник* -- *куст* или *кустар*?

По Тихонову корень ***куст.*** А вот что такое у него ***ар/ник***?

Из его "Словообразовательного словаря русского языка" (М., 1990):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Косая черта в ***ар/ник*** у Тихонова отделяет  интерфикс ***ар***  от суффикса ***ник***. При невыделении при морфемном членении слов интерфиксов они присоединяются либо к корню, либо к суффиксу. См. у Литневской: ["Что же касается интерфиксов второй группы, используемых в словообразовании, существует три точки зрения…"](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm#7)

Панов и Текучев ("Школьный грамматико-орфографический словарь русского языка", М., 1985) этот ***ар*** присоединили к суффиксу. У них в слове ***кустарник*** корень -- ***куст***, суффикс -- ***арник***:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суффикс ***арник*** в слове кустарник отмечает и [Ефремова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/135885).

Comment: Слава, это тот самый сайт ( в скруншоте у Галины), с админом с которым у меня вышел спор.

Answer (score 1):

Понимаю Ваши затруднения: онлайн-словари расходятся в определении корня (обоих слов).

Предлагаю фрагмент ответа опытного учителя русского языка, составителя ряда учебников и методических пособий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заблокированная ссылка - это словарь Тихонова, к которому сейчас не подберёшься.

В слове "кустарник" я тоже не вижу причины игнорировать корень "куст":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И другой словарик это подтверждает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посткриптум.

Нашла статью, где сообщается, что слова *высь, даль* (и, думаю, туда же *ширь*) образовались раньше прилагательных, с которыми их сейчас соотносят:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. также: ***[Существительные с суф. -ник/-атник/-арник/-овник](http://rusgram.narod.ru/328-379.html)***.

Comment: Галина, этому сайту в морфемном разборе не стоит доверять. Очень много ошибок.