# Еще раз о кустарнике (разбор по составу)

Tags: морфемный-разбор

В Сети обозначено **противостояние** разных мнений: куда отнести формант ***АР*** при разборе?

1. Вот как решается задача **[в учебных материалах](https://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%9A/%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA):**

   ```
   Состав слова: куст — корень, ар, ник — суффиксы, 
   нулевое окончание, кустарник — основа слова.
   ```
2. А это **[обсуждение вопроса](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4331286-v-kakih-slovah-suffiks--ar--kustar-kustarnik-ponomar-car-radar-ar.html)**

   ```
   Чтобы ответить на вопрос, обращусь к любимым моим 
   словарям. У Тихонова: куст/ар/ник; у Потиха: 
   куст/арник. Один выделяет суффикс -ар-, а другой 
   — нет.
   ```

**На [форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419957/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)** тема также обсуждалась, и был уточнен разбор **у Тихонова**: ***АР*** — это на самом деле **интерфикс.** Почему пользователи этого не видят?

К сожалению, **не видят**, поэтому вопрос остается. А как же его **решить?** Может быть, надо дать **оценку** этим вариантам разбора? Не хватает **осознанности** в принятии решений.

Поэтому у меня такие  **вопросы:**

(1) Чем **отличаются** эти варианты, можно ли выбрать **правильный**? Что подходит для **школы**, а что выходит за рамки школьной программы?

(2) Если выделять суффикс ***АР***, то с каким **значением?**

Answer (score 1):

1. Существуют  два разных подхода к морфемному членению слова: (1) **формально-структурный** и (2) **формально-семантический.**
   В **первом** случае в слове выделяются **морфемы**, которые знакомы носителям современного языка, при этом не учитываются их **конкретные** значения и реальные **словообразовательные** связи. Во **втором** случае строится **словообразовательная** цепочка. Первый метод применяется на начальном этапе обучения, а второй  является более продвинутым.
2. Но в реальности может использоваться **нечто среднее**, что характерно для словаря **Тихонова.** Там обозначен именно **интерфикс **АР**** (иначе говоря, фонетическая надставка), но не суффикс ***АР***: ***куст — куст/ар|ник.*** Формант ***АРНИК*** — словообразовательный. У **Потиха** также выделен  этот формант.
3. А вот в учебных материалах разбор такой: ***куст/ар/ник.*** Это **формально-структурный** (упрощенный) подход, где обозначен обобщенный суффикс существительного ***АР***. Но конкретного значения у этого суффикса **нет** (по словарю Ефремовой нельзя подобрать нужное значение).

Аналогичная словообразовательная схема, у слова: ***малин/а — малин/ник***, где  суффикс ***НИК*** по сути тоже формант (Н + ИК).